# Powershell login with username and password parameterized

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

in the powershell script for building continous deployment using VSTS do i need to include login-azurermaccount and if yes how do i parameterize it for user name and password.I have googled it and not able to find a correct solution..

Comment: Use the `Azure PowerShell Script` task and you don't need to authenticate within your script. The subscription endpoint already has the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MSCloud services, without being logged into them.

You'd parametrize the creds in the same way you'd do it for on-prem resources that require credentials.

See the built-in help files on credential handling.

```
# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Get-Credential).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-Credential -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Credential -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Credential -Online

Get-Help about_*

# All Help topics locations
explorer "$pshome\$($Host.CurrentCulture.Name)"
```

Or using the PSCredentialObject.

PowerShell – How to create a PSCredential object

Several PowerShell commandlets take a PSCredential object to run using a particular user account. You can create the PSCredential object by using Get-Credential commandlet which opens a dialog to enter the username and password. This way of entering credentials can be used in an interactive mode.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends using an Azure service Principal for power shell automation. You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-5.3.0) on how to create an Azure service Principal.